# How do I check and insert missing variables in each line in file with python?

Tags: python, variables, replace, text-files, missing-data

My csv-file looks something like this:

> **f1**="12345" **f2**="abc" **f3**="cba" **f4**="123abc" **f5**="N" 
>   **f1**="12345" **f2**="abc" **f4**="123abc" **f5**="Y" 
>   **f1**="12345" **f2**="abc" **f3**="cba" **f5**="Y" **f6**="0"

As you can see, some of the f-variables is missing.

How can i use python to make the file look like this?

> **f1**="12345" **f2**="abc" **f3**="cba" **f4**="123abc" **f5**="N" **f6**="NA"
>   **f1**="12345" **f2**="abc" **f3**="NA" **f4**="123abc" **f5**="Y" **f6**="NA"
>   **f1**="12345" **f2**="abc" **f3**="cba" **f4**="NA" **f5**="Y" **f6**="0"

I need all the variables to insert the file into a `mysql-table.`

I have tried functions for checking if not in line and if in line else and line.find, but no luck.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: If you want to get technical the examlple files you gave are not CSVs.

Comment: No it is not csv, it is converted from xml. Next step is to replace f1, f2, f3 and so on with semicolon.

Comment: Here is my code: with open(file, 'U') as f:
    line=f.read()
    while not '" f3="' in line:
        line=line.replace('" f4="', '" f3="NA" f4="')
    else:
        line=line.replace('" f3="', '" f3="')

with open(file, "w") as f:
    f.write(line)

Comment: Wait, are the contents of each cell in the csv the "f1=x" things? Or are those variables you are defining?

Comment: The variables in the csv-file is from an export from an application ex. f1="12345". I need to define the missing variables with ex. f2="NA". Why I put " f3="NA" f4=" in the script is to have a start and endingpoint that is not part of the content of a cell, and that the cell must be inserted in the right position.

Answer (score 0):

Did find a solution with php:

```
<?php

$input = fopen("startfile.csv", "r");
$output = fopen("endfile.csv", "w");

if ($input) {
    while (($line = fgets($input)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
    echo $line;

    if (strpos($line,'" f5="') !==false) {
    //echo "Yes";
    } else {
    //echo "No";
    $line = str_replace('" f6="', '" f5="NA" f6="', $line);
    }

    if (strpos($line,'" f4="') !==false) {
    //echo "Yes";
    } else {
    //echo "No";
    $line = str_replace('" f5="', '" f4="NA" f5="', $line);
    }

    if (strpos($line,'" f3="') !==false) {
    //echo "Yes";
    } else {
    //echo "No";
    $line = str_replace('" f4="', '" f3="NA" f4="', $line);
    }

    echo $line;
    fwrite($output, $line);
    }

    fclose($input);

} else {
    // error opening the file.
}

?>
```